# Colour path segments from scanned illustration

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, path, illustration, pathfinder

I have scanned some drawings for a study project and need to colour the people, dog and other items.

I have image traced but the grouping of paths is inconsistent and not all form complete editable paths.

I want the fastest way to colour the individual path segments.

What techniques are available to retain clean path segments for colouring?

[image]

[image]

How can I cut/divide paths so all are editable like the pink section in the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question you want to add colour to the spaces between the black lines?
I would trace the picture and remove all white. Then draw a frame around the picture, just touching the water + boat lines. Then group image and frame so that you can use the paint bucket tool (K). You might need to close large gaps in the image. You can use the blob brush for that.
[image]

Another way is to add a layer beneath the outline layer, where you simply paint with the Blob brush tool (shift + b). This also makes it easier to edit colours  as it will be fewer shapes to edit.

Comment: Thanks Mikael, I ended up expanding the graphic beyond the canvas edge then using the eraser to cut into separate sections. I will use your technique next time.